# Why ssh.socket is set to conflict with ssh.service (Ubuntu 18.04.3)?

Tags: ssh, systemd, sshd, systemd-unit

## Description of condition

I ran into a strange condition with systemd and ssh on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I checked the status of the `ssh.socket` unit:

```
$ systemctl status ssh.socket
● ssh.socket - OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
   Listen: [::]:22 (Stream)
 Accepted: 0; Connected: 0
```

And it was inactive, however I was logged in with ssh at the very same time and service itself was running, and SSH's socket and corresponding port was open:

```
$ lsof -P -i -n | grep sshd
sshd      26785            root    3u  IPv4 14858764      0t0  TCP 10.200.130.28:22->10.100.40.141:42188 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      26875          xxx_root    3u  IPv4 14858764      0t0  TCP 10.200.130.28:22->10.100.40.141:42188 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      63859            root    3u  IPv4   238437      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      63859            root    4u  IPv6   238439      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

So I looked into the unit file of ssh.socket at `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket`:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket
Before=ssh.service
Conflicts=ssh.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Socket]
ListenStream=22
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Because of the `Before=ssh.service` directive it should be started before the ssh service, and the `Conflicts=ssh.service` directive will cause it to stop when the ssh service starts.

Which explains why it happens in the aspect of unit files, but rise other questions.

## Questions

Why the inactive state of the ssh.socket unit has no effect on the actual ssh socket?

Why the maintainers added the `Conflict` directive? For example if you check the unit file of `docker.socket` it is not set to conflict with the `docker.service`. How the case of sshd differs?

## Additional info

I also checked this on a old fedora 30 workstation. It has the same condition, with minor differences: it uses `sshd.service` and `sshd.socket` as unit names and there is no `Before` directive in the `sshd.socket` unit file.

On both system I have not noticed any resulting problem from this condition, and I suspect that it has some purpose, but cannot find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A systemd socket is a special type of unit that causes systemd to itself bind to the port (or other resource, such as a unix domain socket file path) and spawn a new instance of a service for any connection. With ssh.service enabled, its sshd that runs continuously and binds to the socket, as your lsof shows. Having ssh.socket on instead would mean sshd does not run continuously, but rather an instance of it is invoked only to handle the one client. And in contrast it would show systemd listening on port 22. Because systemd and sshd cannot both listen on the same port, ssh.socket specifies ssh.service as conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to understand is that what you are seeing is one specific usage of "socket" units, in total, there are **three**: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/inetd.html

So in the specific case of `ssh.socket`, this is the equivalent of old-style **inetd-like invocation** (core socket unit setting: `Accept=yes`), where every incoming request on port 22 (managed by systemd) causes the start of a separate `ssh@.service` **instance**.

See also the systemd.socket man page: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html

> If Accept=yes is set, a service template foo@.service must exist from which services are instantiated for each incoming connection

So, there are in total two different ways to start sshd:

- `ssh.service` (`sshd.service` is just an alias) starts the main sshd process and from there forward the process handles all incoming connections, spawns child processes, etc. etc.
- `ssh.socket` + `ssh@.service`, here systemd connects every incoming connection from the socket managed port to a new instance of ssh@.service, inetd-style. This is why in the template service, `StandardInput=socket`, and `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd` has the `-i` option.

Obviously, only one approach can be used at a time, so `Conflicts=` ensures that both aren't running simultaneously. (btw: the actual placement of the `Conflicts=` stanza is not important, an equivalent stanza could have been written in ssh.service, but one is enough)